# Microsoft Graph API Response Schema

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a library that will consume and process JSON from a Graph API (the Users/Mail interface) and I wanted to build in a process to validate the JSON coming from Graph before I try to process it.

I wanted to use a JSON Schema to validate (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) but I can't seem to find the schema for any response, but these are the important ones for me

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{messageID}/attachments
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

Can someone either bust my bubbly or point me toward where I can find the schema files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Graph metadata used for generating client code files](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata).